# Do tickets expire?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

*StreetPass Mii Plaza* 3.1 introduces tickets that can be redeemed for hats. The hats change daily, do the tickets also expire when the hats change or not?

Comment: @DavidStarkey StreetPass Mii Plaza is built into the Nintendo 3DS operating system.

Comment: Just realized what I asked.... stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the hats change, the tickets do not go away unless spent on a hat.